# how to get mouse drag direction in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mouse, mesh

Hello guys I am building a 3D game that player can reshape something like slime with dragging it. the shaping part is alright and I do not have a problem with it.
I use mesh manipulation for shaping my object and I move all vertices within a specific radius of clicked position. but my vertices are moving toward its normal vector I figured that out I can move vertices toward mouse drag vector by just changing normal vectors.

so, here is my question how can I get mouse drag vector so I can change my normal vector to that?

also the player can rotate around X And Y Axis on my object and this makes this problem a little more difficult.

because for example if I see my object from this angle `(270,0,0)` if players drag mouse to right and down my object should Stretch to its -x Axis and -z Axis.

Comment: That depends on exactly what you want to do. Since the movement of the mouse is in 2D and you want to map it in 3D, there are infinitely many ways to do that. I'd say it's probably better to cast it on the surface perpendicular to the normal vector.
Also, can you explain what you mean with "if I see my object from this angle `(270,0,0)`"?